# Best way to refactor two classes with very similar methods?

Tags: c#, interface, refactoring, abstract-class

I have two independent classes and both contain the same method names (start, validation, etc...).

However, the parameters that the methods are expecting are different between both classes.

For instance... I have something similar to this:

```
public static class A
{
    public static void Start(string a, string b) ...implementation inside of it

    public static void Validate (string a, FileInfo b) ...implementation inside of it
}


public static class B
{
     public static void Start (string a) ...implementation inside of it

     public static void Validate(string a, string h FileInfo b, string[] c) ...implementation inside of it
}
```

Is there a way to refactor this with a better code from a design pov? both methods share some common code as well.

I tried to create an Interface (I had to remove the static from both classes) but at the end it was a mess in the sense that I have to implement each of the 4 methods in class A and B which is not what I am looking for.

Will be great if I can get some sort of insights about this. Is an interface what I need? maybe and abstract class? any other thing?

Comment: To answer, we need more information about what the classes are supposed to do in a semantical sense. Maybe there is a way to make the parameters equal; maybe some parts of the functionality can be extracted into another class. It depends.

Comment: I agree with @valenterry: I wouldn't do _any_ refactoring just based on the information you've provided. On the surface, the two classes are only related by having methods with the same names, but different parameters! It's possible that the methods have nothing to do with each other. Anything they have in common will be a question of how they are implemented. I might wind up refactoring the _implementation_, but I wouldn't refactor the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

What I would in this case would be to group the input parameters of the Validate function into a new class

```
public static class Params {
    public string a,
    public FileInfo b
}
```

Then extend this class to

```
public static class ExtendedParams extends Params {
    public string h,
    public string[] c
}
```

Then my original A, B classes could use the same interface

```
interface iAB {
    public Start(string a, string b)
    public Validate(Params c)
}
```

Each class would implemented Start and Validate differently, but class B would expect ExtentedParams as input, so you would have to cast it to ExtendedParams to access the extra fields.

If you'ld need a more clean approach, depending on your semantics of your objects, the Params object should expose an interface with the actions you want to perform on them (or their data) and let them handle the logic. For example (building on the previous example):

```
public static class Params {
    public string a,
    public FileInfo b,
    public void validate()
}

public static class ExtendedParams extends Params {
    public string h,
    public string[] c,
    public void validate()   // implements its own validation
}
```

In the end, it really depends on your own logic within your system, but that would be the directions I would follow.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler approach, IMO. The classes both started out static and you undid that because you wanted either an interface-based or inheritance-based solution. A simpler approach could be overloaded methods in a single class.

This means that you would collapse the methods into a single, static class which would have multiple overloaded methods. This would make your refactoring simpler and also allow you to re-use the common code more easily inside the "unified" class.

So, something like this:

```
public static class AB // combined
{
    public static void Start(string a, string b) ...implementation inside of it

    public static void Validate (string a, FileInfo b) ...implementation inside of it

    public static void Start (string a) ...implementation inside of it

    public static void Validate(string a, string h FileInfo b, string[] c) ...implementation inside of it

    private static string SomeCommonFunctionality(string a, string h) ...implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional parameters. This depends on what your code is doing as to whether this is a viable solution.

```
public static class B
{
     public static void Start (string a, string b = string.empty)
     {
          //common code
          if (b != string.empty)
          {
              var s = SomethingSpecific(string y)
          }
          //common code
     }
     public static void Validate(string a, string h FileInfo b, string[] c = null)
     {

     }

     private static string SomethingSpecific(string y)
     {
          //Do some custom logic here
     }
}
```